# How to delete non empty S3 bucket using aws-java-sdk 2.0

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am able to delete a non-empty bucket using `aws-java-sdk 1.0` but not with aws-java-sdk 2.0. Here is the code:

**Not working code with aws-java-sdk 2.0 for deleting non empty s3 bucket:**

```
{
            boolean isTruncated = true;
            while(isTruncated) {
                ListObjectsV2Iterable objectListing = s3Client.listObjectsV2Paginator(ListObjectsV2Request.builder()
                        .bucket(bucketName)
                        .build());
                for (ListObjectsV2Response response : objectListing) {
                    /*
                     * There could be many pages in object list response is just one page
                     * */
                    for (S3Object s3Object : response.contents()) {
                        s3Client.deleteObject(DeleteObjectRequest.builder()
                                .bucket(bucketName)
                                .key(s3Object.key())
                                .build());
                    }
                    isTruncated = response.isTruncated();
                }
            }


            // Delete all object versions (required for versioned buckets).
            ListObjectVersionsIterable versionList = s3Client.listObjectVersionsPaginator(ListObjectVersionsRequest.builder()
                    .bucket(bucketName)
                    .build());
            isTruncated = true;

            while (isTruncated) {
                for (ListObjectVersionsResponse response : versionList) {
                    for (ObjectVersion version : response.versions()) {
                        s3Client.deleteObject(DeleteObjectRequest.builder()
                                .bucket(bucketName)
                                .key(version.key())
                                .versionId(version.versionId())
                                .build());
                    }
                    isTruncated = response.isTruncated();
                }
            }

        s3Client.deleteBucket(DeleteBucketRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).build());
    }
```

Above code is unable to delete bucket, it throws exception:

> software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket. (Service: S3, Status Code: 409, Request ID: F5D76141223DC5EA)

**Working code with aws-java-sdk 1.0 for deleting non empty bucket:**

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName);
            while (true) {
                Iterator<S3ObjectSummary> objIter = objectListing.getObjectSummaries().iterator();
                while (objIter.hasNext()) {
                    s3Client.deleteObject(bucketName, objIter.next().getKey());
                }

                // If the bucket contains many objects, the listObjects() call
                // might not return all of the objects in the first listing. Check to
                // see whether the listing was truncated. If so, retrieve the next page of objects
                // and delete them.
                if (objectListing.isTruncated()) {
                    objectListing = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Delete all object versions (required for versioned buckets).
            VersionListing versionList = s3Client.listVersions(new ListVersionsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName));
            while (true) {
                Iterator<S3VersionSummary> versionIter = versionList.getVersionSummaries().iterator();
                while (versionIter.hasNext()) {
                    S3VersionSummary vs = versionIter.next();
                    s3Client.deleteVersion(bucketName, vs.getKey(), vs.getVersionId());
                }

                if (versionList.isTruncated()) {
                    versionList = s3Client.listNextBatchOfVersions(versionList);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            // After all objects and object versions are deleted, delete the bucket.
            s3Client.deleteBucket(bucketName);
```

Comment: So, what's the cause of the non-empty message? Is there anything left in the bucket? You'll need to check all versions and even [partial multipart uploads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html). Are you saying that the v1 code will delete a bucket that the v2 code cannot? (You tested it on the same bucket, after getting the v2 error?) Is it due to objects, or is it due to versioned objects?

Comment: this is due to versioned objects.

Comment: To clarify, you are saying that the section of your v2 code that is meant to delete versioned objects is not actually deleting them? Is it deleting _any_ of the versions, or is it deleting none of them?

Comment: Are you sure you need `isTruncated()`? The code is using `listObjectVersionsPaginator`, which should keep providing values.

Comment: 1. I added isTruncated() later, just to see if it works that way.
2. The content of the first page of versioned objects itself is empty. So it's not about deleting versioned objects, it's about it is not fetching versioned objects.

Comment: I'm not a Java person, but if the call is not returning versioned objects when there _are_ versioned objects, then I think you've found the line that is having the problem. Try it without using a Paginator and see whether objects are returned, then work your way up from there.

Answer (score 0):

I checked each DeleteObjectResponse for any failure. If all responses show success then delete the bucket. Here is working code for objects, it should work for versions too.

```
public void delete(String bucketName)
{
    amazonS3Client.listObjectsV2(bucketName).stream().map(this::toDeleteObjectRequests).forEach(this::deleteBucket);
}

private List<DeleteObjectRequest> toDeleteObjectRequests(ListObjectsV2Response res)
{
    List<DeleteObjectRequest> deleteObjectRequests = res.contents().stream()
    .map(object -> DeleteObjectRequest.builder().bucket(res.name()).key(object.key()).build())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    if(deleteObjectRequests.isEmpty())
    {
        log.info("Bucket :{}: is empty deleting", res.name());
        amazonS3Client.deleteBucket(DeleteBucketRequest.builder().bucket(res.name()).build());
    }
    return deleteObjectRequests;
}

private void deleteBucket(List<DeleteObjectRequest> deleteObjects)
{
    deleteObjects.stream().findFirst().ifPresent(object -> deleteObjectsAndBucket(deleteObjects, object));
}

private void deleteObjectsAndBucket(List<DeleteObjectRequest> deleteObjects, DeleteObjectRequest object)
{
    Optional<DeleteObjectResponse> notDeletedObject = deleteAllObjects(deleteObjects);
    if (!notDeletedObject.isPresent())
    {
        log.info("Deleting bucket {} after emptying", object.bucket());
        amazonS3Client.deleteBucket(DeleteBucketRequest.builder().bucket(object.bucket()).build());
    }
    else
    {
        log.info("{} could not be deleted", notDeletedObject.get());
    }
}

private Optional<DeleteObjectResponse> deleteAllObjects(List<DeleteObjectRequest> deleteObjects)
{
    Optional<DeleteObjectResponse> notDeletedObject = deleteObjects.stream().map(amazonS3Client::deleteObject)
            .filter(res -> !res.sdkHttpResponse().isSuccessful()).findFirst();
    return notDeletedObject;
}
```

You need to modify above code to handle pagination as per @lu_ko suggestion.
Here is a link to github source-code for [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/5ca9e90360a3c27ae7a394d069ec70dc206b25ce/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.java)

Comment: You should check `isTruncated()` to verify if the bucket contains many objects, and if the single `listObjectsV2()` call returned just first page of objects or all objects.